# Filtrar una dataframe con un elemento seleccionado en un dropdown produce Cannot read property 'layout' of null

Tags: python, pandas, dropdownlist, plotly, dash

Tengo una dataframe df multiíndice cuyos quiero mostrar las valores en un dashboard sólo si el índice ha sido seleccionado en un dropdown. Por ejemplo el indice My Burberry en la siguiente dataframe:

```
                            claimed_benefit perceived_benefit
My Burberry Je me sens bien     0           0.000000
            romantique          0           0.000000
            convient bien moi   0           0.000000
            féminin             0           0.033898
            sensuelle / sexy    0           0.000000
... ... ... ...
The Beat    harsh / agressif    0           0.000000
            boisé               0           0.000000
            écœurant            0           0.000000
            strength1           0           0.000000
            marron              0           0.000000
```

Por el momento no puedo filtrar porque produce un error `Cannot read property 'layout' of null` cuando intento utilisar el value del Dropdown.

Aqui esta el Dashboard sin filtrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pueden ver que en cada uno de los valores del eje x todos los valores están apilados. Estos son los índices. Aquí está el código que produce este dashboard.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("cb_pb.csv", index_col=0)

traces = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    trace_claimed = go.Bar(x=[df.iloc[i].values[0]], y=[df.iloc[i].values[2]], name='Claimed')
    trace_perceived = go.Bar(x=[df.iloc[i].values[0]], y=[-df.iloc[i].values[1]], name='Perceived')
    traces.append(trace_claimed)
    traces.append(trace_perceived)

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

])

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children='Scores of perfumes over claimed attributes'),
    html.Div(children='''National Sales Funnel Report.'''),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='demo-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df.index.unique()],
        value='My Burberry - Eau de Parfum'
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': traces,
            'layout':
            go.Layout(title='Order Status by Customer', barmode='stack')
        })
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Así que para filtrar estos índices intenté vincular el valor producido por el dropdown a una función que produce el gráfico filtrando los trazos a dibujar con `if dfc.iloc[i].name == my_dropdown`:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv("cb_pb.csv", index_col=0)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children='Scores of perfumes over claimed attributes'),
    html.Div(children='''National Sales Funnel Report.'''),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='perfume-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df.index.unique()],
        value='My Burberry - Eau de Parfum'
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='the_graph')
    ])
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='the_graph', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id="perfume-dropdown", component_property="value")]
)
def update_graph(my_dropdown):
    dfc = df
    traces = []
    for i in range(len(dfc)):
        if dfc.iloc[i].name == my_dropdown:
            trace_claimed = go.Bar(x=[dfc.iloc[i].values[0]], y=[dfc.iloc[i].values[2]], name='Claimed')
            trace_perceived = go.Bar(x=[dfc.iloc[i].values[0]], y=[-dfc.iloc[i].values[1]], name='Perceived')
            traces.append(trace_claimed)
            traces.append(trace_perceived)
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': traces,
            'layout':
                go.Layout(title='Order Status by Customer', barmode='stack')
        })

@app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    [Input('perfume-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Pero me devuelve `Cannot read property 'layout' of null`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]